# How to correctly handle scanf()

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I have to take input in the following format

```
S1 S2 S3
```

where S1 is a character and S2,S3 are integers
for example

```
 3
 A 123 452
 D 450 53
 B 330 672
```

(where the '3' represents the number of queries)
Now I've written the following code for it :

```
 while(i<=Q){
          scanf("%c %d %d",&ch,&index,&num);
          printf("%c %d %d\n",ch,index,num);
          i++;
 }
```

However, for the above shown three values I am getting the following output

```
 0 755130840
A 123 452

 123 452
```

with an extra line at the top and that large value (here 755130840) changing every time.

Where am I going wrong?? I even tried scanning the 3 values individually and flushing the input stream before each scan statement. However, It doesn't help either.

Given the two blank lines, I believe the newline ('\n') is being stored in some variable.How do I handle it?

Comment: Hint: use the return value. (yes: scanf() has a return value!)

Comment: put a space before `%c` in `scanf`

Comment: How come that worked?? Yeah I mean it had to..but can you elaborate a little ?(probably as an answer which I can upvote..:) )

Comment: @alphacentauri select a right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space before %c in scanf. This will allow scanf to skip any number of white spaces before reading `ch`.
`scanf` with blank skips white space (including newlines) and reads the next character that is not white space.

Here is a code , this would be working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int i =0;
    int Q = 2;
    char ch;
    int index;
    int num;
    while(i<=Q){
          scanf(" %c %d %d",&ch,&index,&num);
          printf("%c %d %d\n",ch,index,num);
          i++;
 }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1, Post the code here. Don't answer with a outside link only.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

        int num, count, numone, numtwo;
        char charip;
        printf("Enter numbr of elem:\t");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num < 0)
        {
                printf("Enter positive value!!!!!\n");
                exit (-1);
        }
        count = 0;
        while (count < num)
        {
                getchar();
                scanf ("%c %d %d", &charip, &numone, &numtwo)   ;
                printf("%c %d %d\n", charip, numone, numtwo);
                count++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: add count++ otherwise it would go into infinite loop

Comment: Did you tried it... how can you forgot to increment the counter?

Comment: sorry..my bad. Thanks for the comments.